# I cannot parse in python multiple xml files

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath

i am trying to get data from xml files, using 1 xml file my code works and i have all the data that i need, but when i try to get my code work using diferrents xml files it fails, all the xml have the same elements and in the same positions.

i have tried use glob and list dir with os but is not working and when i execute the python .py from the terminal doesn't return me nothing.

My working code for just one xml file :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('provaDmarcXml2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
org_name = root[0][0].text


domain = root[1][0].text

LlistaSource_ip = []
LlistaDkim = []
LlistaSpf = []
for source_ip in root.iter('source_ip'):
    sourceIp = source_ip.text
    LlistaSource_ip.append(sourceIp)

for dkim in root.findall("./record/row/policy_evaluated/dkim"):
    Dkim = dkim.text
    LlistaDkim.append(Dkim)


for spf in root.findall("./record/row/policy_evaluated/spf"):
    Spf = spf.text
    LlistaSpf.append(Spf)

for c in range(len(LlistaSource_ip)):
    print (org_name,"\t",end = "")
    print (domain,"\t",end='')
    print (LlistaSource_ip[c],"\t", end="")
    print (LlistaDkim[c],"\t", end="")
    print (LlistaSpf[c],"\t", end="")
    print()
```

---

My code doesn't work trying to parse multiple xml files in the same directory.

```
from os import listdir
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


for file in listdir("path to directory"):

    with open(file, "rb"):

        tree = ET.parse(data)

        root = tree.getroot()
        org_name = root[0][0].text
        domain = root[1][0].text

        LlistaSource_ip = []
        LlistaDkim = []
        LlistaSpf = []

        for source_ip in root.iter('source_ip'):
            sourceIp=source_ip.text
            LlistaSource_ip.append(sourceIp)

        for dkim in root.findall("./record/row/policy_evaluated/dkim"):
            Dkim = dkim.text
            LlistaDkim.append(Dkim)

    for spf in root.findall("./record/row/policy_evaluated/spf"):
            Spf = spf.text
        LlistaSpf.append(Spf)

    for c in range(len(LlistaSource_ip)):
        print()
```

Expected results :

data    data    data    data    data
data    data    data    data    data
data    data    data    data    data
data    data    data    data    data

from all the files

error that i get :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "provaxmlPrograma2.py", line 10, in 
    tree = ET.parse(data)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

or it doesn't return me nothing if i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your **open()** statement, you have to define it like shown below.

You could also add a check if **file.endswith()** to make sure you are just trying to parse the xml files of your folder.

```
from os import listdir
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for file in listdir('path to file'):
    if file.endswith('.xml') or file.endswith('.XML'):
        with open(file, "rb") as data:

            tree = ET.parse(data)
            root = tree.getroot()
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much everyone,

I was getting crazy about this and i didn't know why was happening, this fixed my problem.

Thanks a lot.